# Почему не работают `breakpoint`

Tags: django, pycharm, breakpoint

Имеется проект на Django и использую PyCharm. Когда я локально запускаю проект и использую `breakpoint` в используемом Python-файле, то проект не останавливается на `breakpoint`.

Так и должно быть при разработке с использованием `Django`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы работали "отметки приостановки", надо запускать проект с помощью отладчика (иконка изображающая жучка, рядом со стрелкой).

Comment: Когда перешел с Python на WEB-разработку с использованием Django, то пришлось много дополнительного изучать. А теперь самому очень смешно от того, что забыл про такую мелочь. :-D Спасибо!